# DataBind a Dictionary value to ObservableCollection C# - XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, binding

I've got a Observable collection of custom objects and a public dictionary variable.

I would like the "BrandName" attribute to act as the Key for the "Brands" dictionary and bind the colour to the button. How would I go about doing this? The dictionary variable is outside of the class.

C# Code:

```
private ObservableCollection<BusService> BusServicesGUI;
public Dictionary<String, Brush> Brands;

public MainWindow(Dictionary<String, BusService> busServices)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BusServicesGUI = new ObservableCollection<BusService>(BusServices.Values);
    lstMachineFunctions.ItemsSource = BusServicesGUI;
    lstMachineFunctions.Items.Refresh();
}
```

C# Class:

```
public class BusService
{
    public string ServiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public BusService(string brandName, string serviceNumber)
    {
        BrandName = brandName;
        ServiceNumber = serviceNumber; 
        Locations = new List<Location>();
    }
}
```

XAML CODE:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ServiceStack">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="lstMachineFunctions">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate>   
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <usercontrols:BusServiceCard/>
                     <Button Tag="{Binding ServiceNumber}" Background="{Binding Brands[BrandName]}" Height="50" Click="ButtonCl"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see from the XAML my current attempts have been trying `Background="{Binding Brands[BrandName]}"` This has however not worked, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it a complex brush or just a `SolidColorBrush`? Would it be possible to put a `Color` on `BusService`?

Comment: Its only just a SolidColourBrush, I don't want to add a colour attribute to the BusService class however as I want to be able to change the brand dictionary and it update all of the bus service objects.

Comment: Make a viewmodel that wraps around BusService (e.g. BusServiceViewModel), have it provide the color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an IValueConverter to pefrom this operation.

```
public class BrandColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Dictionary<String, Brush> Brands = new Dictionary<string, Brush>()
    {
        { "brand1", Brushes.Red },
        { "brand2", Brushes.Blue }
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is BusService))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        var busService = (BusService)value;

        if (!Brands.ContainsKey(busService.BrandName))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return Brands[busService.BrandName];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

In xaml, add it as a static resuorce:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BrandColorConverter x:Key="BrandColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it in your button:

```
  <Button Tag="{Binding ServiceNumber}" 
     Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrandColorConverter}}" 
     Height="50" 
     Click="ButtonCl"/>
```

This binding goes to the current element, so the whole BusService object will be passed to the converter.

Hope it solves your problem.

I would strongly advise you to look into MVVM pattern if you are going to use WPF with data binding, as it makes things much more streamlined.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's done just the trick, I'll be sure to look into MVVM as suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: IMO this is also a nice solution in that it keeps the concern of "which color to display for which widget" out of the view model.